# Crystal Report Show Database query

Tags: crystal-reports

I am a newbie at CR.  I have a report that someone else created.  When I use the Database -> 'Show SQL Query' command the WHERE clause has a bunch of names.  How can I find out where this list of names is coming from?

```
SELECT "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."date_of_service", "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."v_SERVICE_CODE",     "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."v_PROVIDER_NAME",     "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."service_status_value", "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."v_client_name", "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."guarantor_liability", "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."CLAIM_NUMBER", "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."GUARANTOR_ID", "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."v_service_value", "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."PATID", "cw_patient_notes"."service_duration", "cw_patient_notes"."note_type_value"FROM   "SYSTEM"."billing_tx_charge_detail_2004" "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004" LEFT OUTER JOIN "CWSAVPMLIVESYSTEM"."cw_patient_notes" "cw_patient_notes" ON ((("billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."FACILITY"="cw_patient_notes"."FACILITY") AND ("billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."PATID"="cw_patient_notes"."PATID")) AND ("billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."EPISODE_NUMBER"="cw_patient_notes"."EPISODE_NUMBER")) AND ("billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."JOIN_TO_TX_HISTORY"="cw_patient_notes"."JOIN_TO_TX_HISTORY")
WHERE  ("billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."date_of_service">={d '2009-07-01'} 
AND "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."date_of_service"<={d '2009-07-31'}) AND 
("billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."v_PROVIDER_NAME"='BARNHART,SCOTT' OR
 "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."v_PROVIDER_NAME"='BINKER,BARB  MSW LISW' OR 
"billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."v_PROVIDER_NAME"='BRETNAN,BAUNEEN' OR 
"billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."v_PROVIDER_NAME"='CROWN,DWAYNE  BS  NCAC-I  LADAC' 
OR "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."v_PROVIDER_NAME"='COFFEE,RAMBA  BA  LADAC' OR
"billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."v_PROVIDER_NAME"='DECODE,TENISE  MC LMFT LADAC' OR 
"billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."v_PROVIDER_NAME"='GONSALEZ,MAREN' OR
"billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."v_PROVIDER_NAME"='HITAN,TOM' OR 
"billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."v_PROVIDER_NAME"='KOTUE,SHEENA')
 ORDER BY "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."v_SERVICE_CODE",
 "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."date_of_service", "billing_tx_charge_detail_2004"."PATID"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is found in the Report ->Select Expert command!  Hooray!

I knew as soon as I posted the question I would find the answer  :)

Comment: Just a small recommendation: The Select Expert is used to build up the Record Selection Formula. If you want to look at the raw formula, go to "Report" -> "Selection Formulas" -> "Record". I find it much simpler to just edit the formula directly than use the expert.

Comment: the problem was that the last person hard coded all the names in the Report -> Select Expert section and I needed to remove them.  I prefer to write my own SQL queries...that way I know exactly what data is coming and why

Answer (score 0):

You've got some choices.  It's either:

- In the record selection formula (Report > Edit Selection Formula > Record)
- Hard-coded in the "Show SQL Query" window (though not as likely)
- In a parameter that was either saved with the report, or contains default values (even less likely)